# RelayCommand Class issue

Tags: c#, wpf, lambda

I am new to MVVM. I have made a RelayCommand class but I'm getting some errors with the lambda expression.

```
AddTitleCommand = new RelayCommand(o => true, o => Items.Add(new MyTitleModel()));
```

This line of code is returning an error saying:

**Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement**

```
AddQuestionCommand = new RelayCommand(o => Items.Any(), o =>
{
            var title = this.Items.OfType<MyTitleModel>().LastOrDefault();
            Items.Add(new MyQuestionModel() { Title = title });
});
```

This line of code is returning the error saying:

**Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'System.Predicate  < object>'**

Finally, in the actual class there are 2 properties that need a reference which i cannot seem to find on the internet they are:

```
if (_myCommand == null)
{
            _myCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.DoMyCommand(p),
                p => this.CanDoMyCommand(p));
}
```

The `DoMyCommand` and `CanDoMyCommand` have the error saying:

**'RelayCommand' does not contain a definition for 'DoMyCommand' and no extension method 'DoMyCommand' accepting a first argument of type 'RelayCommand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?**

EDIT1:

Binson Eldhose This is my other piece of code:

```
RelayCommand _myCommand;
public ICommand MyCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_myCommand == null)
        {
            _myCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.DoMyCommand(p),
                p => this.CanDoMyCommand(p));
        }
        return _myCommand;
    }
}
```

EDIT2:

Here are the RelayCommand Constructors:

```
#region Constructors

public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
    : this(execute, null)
{
}

public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
{
    if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentException("execute");
    _execute = execute;
    _canExecute = canExecute;
}
#endregion // Constructors
```

Comment: All the errors are due to invalid parameter types to the `RelayCommand` constructor. Can you add the code for `RelayCommand` also.

Comment: @Mathew Added in the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
AddQuestionCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
{
        var title = this.Items.OfType<MyTitleModel>().LastOrDefault();
        Items.Add(new MyQuestionModel() { Title = title });
 },(p)=>Items.Any());
```

First parameter should be Action and second Func that return Bool . And in your above code its reverse

> Update

```
AddTitleCommand = new RelayCommand( o => Items.Add(new MyTitleModel()),p => true));
```

> Update

```
RelayCommand _myCommand;
public ICommand MyCommand
{
get
{
    if (_myCommand == null)
    {
        _myCommand = new RelayCommand(DoMyCommand,CanDoMyCommand);
    }
    return _myCommand;
}
}

bool CanDoMyCommand(object obj)
    {
        return true;//return true or false accordingly.
    }

    void DoMyCommand(object obj)
    { 
        //Do your work that you want to do on when Command Fires
    }
```

Comment: Get this error `A local variable named 'o' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'o', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else`

Comment: I updated the answer there should not be the param in second param .

Comment: The final line `()=>Items.Any());` returns the error `Delegate 'System.Predicate<object>' does not take 0 arguments`

Comment: Yes, that worked thanks still have the error in the other expression :(

Comment: Which other expression?

Comment: If you look at the question its the first line of code I pasted starting 'AddTitleCommand'

Comment: See the update. Your code is correct except you have passed parameters incorrectly. Means the parameter you passed first should be the second and vice versa

Comment: There is 2 errors on updated code `No overload Method 'Add' takes 2 Arguements` and `A local variable named 'o' cannot be decleared in the scope because it would give a different meaning to 'o', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else`

Comment: The DoMyCommand And CanDoMyCommand say `Do Not exists in current context`

Comment: They must be methods in your class where you have MyCommand. If they not then how you can even use them.See the update

Comment: Yeah, this worked thanks now I need to research what to put into the methods haha thanks for your ehlp

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation of relayCommand

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region Fields

```
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members [DebuggerStepThrough]

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members }
}
```

Usage

```
private RelayCommand _saveCommand;

 public ICommand SaveCommand
        {
            get { return _saveCommand ?? (_saveCommand = new RelayCommand(p => Save(), p => CanSave())); }
        }


    private void Save()
    {

     // Saving code


    }
```

private bool CanSave()
        {
           //
        }

Comment: I have your exact RelayCommand its just I have a bit extra at the bottom which I have added to my updated question for you to see, this is where I need to find the reference.

Comment: if you want to pass a parameter to the predicate take this example

Comment: public ICommand DoMyCommand
        {
            get { return _DoMyCommand?? (_DoMyCommand= new RelayCommand(OnDoCommand)); }   private void OnDeviceChange(object parameter)
        { // your code }  // and parameter must be passed from view 
        }

Comment: imaging you want pass a parameter from buttom use the following <Button Content ="Edit" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" Command="{DoMyCommand}"/>    //  now you can get this parameter in command function

Comment: @bindson Eldhose Thanks i made 2 new methods, just need to add my code into the methods now thanks for your help.